# Successfully deployed change set still shows in 'Awaiting Deployment', can I delete it?

Tags: deployment, change-set, quick-deploy

I have a change set that was successfully deployed but has still been sitting in the *'Change Sets Awaiting Deployment'* queue.

When I click on it the deployment history shows the following:

`Validate: Succeeded 9/22/2017 11:27 AM
 Deploy  : Succeeded 9/20/2017 8:08 PM
 Validate: Succeeded 9/20/2017 7:58 PM`

I don't remember hitting validate again on the change set after deploying it but its totally possible I did, and looks that way.

My question is can I safely delete this change set? I'm assuming that would not rollback the already deployed code but I could not find any documentation on salesforce that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting a deployed change set will not roll back the changes made therein. You can delete this change set without repercussion, as long as you don't count having it missing from your deployment history as such.